# Searching and extracting top retweets using tweepy

Tags: python, tweets, tweepy, python-twitter

I need to extract the top retweets for a given search tag.For that purpose ive done this

```
search = []
page = 1
while(1):
    tweets = api.search(tag,page = page)
    for tweet in tweets:
        search.append(tweet)
    page = page + 1
```

and then from search using regular expressions I managed to extract the top retweets.

But the problem is the loop stops after 330 tweets,and the retweets are from those 330 only.

Is my approach correct,is there a way to scrape more of twitter or is there a more direct way of accessing retweets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a limit in the number of tweet you can get in an hour: 350 from what I understand from [dev twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/faq#checking).

Answer (score 0):

You are limited to 350 api calls per hour.  My understanding is you can get up to 100 tweets per call.